# Error with Leaflet Routing Machine

Tags: route, leaflet

I downloaded the Leaflet Routing Machine from https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine. Unzipped and opened the index.html in my browser to see how it looks, and got an error as shown in the image below:

```
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?instructions=true&loc=57.74,11.94&loc=57.6792,11.949&jsonp=_l_routing_machine_0
```

[image]

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Leaflet OSRM Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/leaflet-routing-machine.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/L.Routing.Autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/L.Routing.OSRM.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/L.Routing.Line.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/L.Routing.Itinerary.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/L.Routing.Plan.js"></script>
    <script src="../src/L.Routing.Control.js"></script>
    <script src="Control.Geocoder.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the _portion_ of the index.html file that is referring to that file location?

Comment: It is exactly the site I quoted index.html. edited the qestão with the code for you to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I **think** that this will not work from your desktop, but needs to be uploaded to a server. These lines [in L.Routing.OSRM.js](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine/blob/master/src/L.Routing.OSRM.js)

```
23  L.Routing.OSRM = L.Class.extend({ 
24      options: { 
25          serviceUrl: '//router.project-osrm.org/viaroute', 
26          geometryPrecision: 6 
27      },
```

are getting `file://` appended to the front (`file://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?...`) instead of `http://` and causing the file-not-found error.

I do not have enough JavaScript experience to help with debugging aside from suggesting you access it from the web instead of your local computer.

Comment: It's enough to pass `serviceUrl: 'http://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute'` to the options. For instance if you are creating `L.Routing.control`, you can write [`something like this`](http://pastebin.com/1Lg7r8t1).